# Why does Ubuntu 18.04 have 2 graphical interfaces?

Tags: 18.04, tty, interface

When I wanted to change from the graphical interface to a non-graphical interface I used the shortcuts Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6] with the one in F1 being the graphical one by default. On the new Ubuntu, F2 is the graphical interface logged in, and F1, logged out. I don't understand this. What's the sense in having those 2?